# Multitenancy with Spring Data and Mongo

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am developing a SaaS application with Spring data and Mongo data with multitenancy on the schema level. So, separation is done on each collection. Each collection has tenant_id.

I managed to implement with Mongo template plus query but in that case, I lose repository abstraction.

What I can not find is how to extend repositories and use all the functions from repository API and add for each query type (find, save, update..) tenant_id in the query?